# Is there any library to find out urls of embedded flvs in a webpage?

Tags: python, download, flv

I'm trying to write a script which can automatically download gameplay videos. The webpages look like dota.sgamer.com/Video/Detail/402 and www.wfbrood.com/movie/spl2009/movie_38214.html, they have flv player embedded in the flash plugin.
Is there any library to help me find out the exact flv urls? or any other ideas to get it?

Many thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Flashticle](http://undefined.org/python/#flashticle) (4th result on searching the cheese shop for "flash"), might be able to get the information you want, if it is there.

As to getting the file, you want to look at a html parser.  I've heard good things about [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  Between that and urllib2 (part of the standard library), you should be able to download the swf file to work on.

Please note that I have never tried this, and am not familiar with flash at all (other than as an end-user, of course).

Answer (score 0):

if the embed player makes use of some variable where the flv path is set then you can download it, if not.. I doubt you find something to do it "automaticly" since every site make it's own player and identify the file by id not by path, which makes hard to know where the flv file is.

Comment: There is a website http://www.flvcd.com/ which can figure out the flv urls in your request, I just want to know how does it work.